# Transform a Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas

Given the fictional data frame:

```
Fruit  Seeds

Apple  Yes
Banana No
Pear   Yes
Apple  Yes
Banana No
```

How can I transform it to the following?

```
Fruit  Yes No Total

Apple  2   0  2
Banana 0   2  2
Pear   1   0  1
```

Comment: Use `pd.crosstab`.

Comment: `df.value_counts()` provides a similar output.

Comment: @Confused Even closer, `df.value_counts().unstack('Seeds').fillna(0)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = pd.crosstab(df['Fruit'], df['Seeds'])
df['Total'] = df['Yes'] + df['No']
print(df.reset_index())

Seeds   Fruit  No  Yes  Total
0       Apple   0    2      2
1      Banana   2    0      2
2        Pear   0    1      1
```